# How do we make Next.js Static Generation getStaticProps() to work on a component level?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

The following code can do Static Generation of Next.js at build time, when it is fetching data at the Home component level:

```js
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const dataAtBuild = await fetch(
    "https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/MTR/84,105/forecast"
  ).then((res) => res.json());

  return {
    props: {
      dataAtBuild
    }
  };
}
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-zhukovsky-l7wb9?file=/pages/index.js

and curling its output using

```
curl https://l7wb9.sse.codesandbox.io/ | grep -o -E '.{30}Time of.{60}'
```

can show

```
<p>Time of forecast: <!-- -->3/12/2021, 6:00:00 AM
```

which is generated at build time.

However, if the code `getStaticProps()` is moved to the component `Weather`, then it cannot have the build time data, as in

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-night-08cz7?file=/pages/Weather.js

And curling it:

```
curl https://08cz7.sse.codesandbox.io/ | grep -o -E '.{30}Time of.{60}'
```

can no longer get the static generated content at build time.

How to make it work at the component level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid it is not possible right now, if you want to have server-side data fetching then it is only possible to have it on [Page Component](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#only-allowed-in-a-page) level.

Quote:

> `getStaticProps` can only be exported from a page. You can’t export it from non-page files.
>
> One of the reasons for this restriction is that React needs to have all the required data before the page is rendered.
>
> Also, you must use export async function `getStaticProps() {}` — it will not work if you add `getStaticProps` as a property of the page component.

You can also read [what counts as Page Component](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages)

Maybe something will arise when React releases server components, I think React team works with NextJs team on it.

https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/pull/188

Comment: it must be Page level? For example, if Page shows Info and Info shows Weather and passes data to Weather, can Info do the `getStaticProps()` if Info is *not* getting any props?   If it must be Page level, then if 2 children components are fetching data, then somehow the page has to fetch both and somehow pass them down to the children components? Are you part of the Next.js team? Because these days I can get 3 opinions from 3 people, I don't know which opinion is the real answer

Comment: (and in those example, the component is not called `Page` but `Home`... I don't see other pages using the name `Page` or `Home`... how is it known this is the "root" component?)

Comment: Here is concrete part with explanation from docs https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#only-allowed-in-a-page

I'll update the answer

Comment: But yes, if your Page renders several different components with different data, then it should fetch the data for all of them and pass it down the tree somehow (usually it is done with React context)